# After waking up from sleep Ubuntu freezes about 20-30 seconds

Tags: 20.04, suspend

Everytime after I wake laptop from suspend mode it freezes for about 20-30 seconds and then let's me to write password for login, this doesn't happen on reboot but only on suspend mode, thanks in advance! I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit on Thinkpad T450s machine!

Comment: Could you let us know what kind of laptop and which version of Ubuntu you're running? There is not enough information here.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 64-bit on Lenovo Thinkpad T450s, this issue happened to me a month after fresh install of OS, Idk if this has to be with an app but it occured just after I installed Steam software!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem on a Thinkpad T440p with Ubuntu 20.04.2 TLS (64-bit).

Uninstalling fprnitd fixed it (the fingerprint login didn't work very well for me anyway):

```
sudo apt remove fprintd
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this solved my problem.

Comment: trying this now. found so many useless suggestions, this is the only one that has suggested its related to the fingerprint scanner (this is the only ubuntu device ive owned with an fprint scanner, so have a good feeling this is the issue)